# Telegraf JS: how can i clear history of a chat?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram-api, telegraf.js

How can i Clear the Chat History, in my case the Bot Chat history with Telegraf.js? I saw in Telegram API that is there a way to clear History of a chat: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteHistory

WIth `messages.deleteHistory()`, but i cannot find nothing on Telegraf docs.

So how can i do with Telegraf to clear the history?

Thank you

Comment: Also, Just for confirmation that `delete_history` isn't available for bots even when using direct mtproto (telegram protocol) based libs, check out [this documentation in telethon](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/delete_history.html) for it

Answer (score 3):

I've tried such a way, but it won't be enough.

```
bot.command('delete', (ctx) =>{
let k = 0;
for(let i = 0; i <= 100; i++ ){
    k =  ctx.message.message_id-i;
    ctx.deleteMessage(k)
}
```

Comment: adding a verbal explanation is often helpful

Answer (score 0):

Telegraf.js uses the official [Telegram BOT Api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) behind the scenes (accessed using HTTP).

And [`messages.deleteHistory()`](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteHistory) is a core API method (accessed using MTProto protocol). Also note that the method can only be invoked by Regular Users and not Bots (even if you consider using a mtproto based libs. to call it)

In other words, Bots can't do that and there isn't such method in the HTTP bot API. The best you can do is use [`deleteMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage).

> Use this method to delete a message, including service messages, with
> the following limitations:
>
> - A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.
> - A dice message in a private chat can only be deleted if it was sent more than 24 hours ago.
> - Bots can delete outgoing messages in private chats, groups, and supergroups.
> - Bots can delete incoming messages in private chats.
> - Bots granted can_post_messages permissions can delete outgoing messages in channels.
> - If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
> - If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there. Returns True on success.

Comment: EHmmm..but i see sometimes BOTS that after done all things (also after 2 days) delete all the chat. Or other that when i play starts deletes all the messages and then they send a message. I utilized one almost 2 weeks ago and deletes all (also sent from more then 2 days). Then i uses wizardscenes so how can i delete a message sent by the bot?

Comment: Well, that's what the official doc. states and note that we're speaking of Telegraf here (which essentially operates via HTTP Bot API).

Comment: These bots most probably are running on some mtproto libraries such as [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/), [pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/), etc.. (since it's allowed to [delete messages without the 48hrs restrictions as of 24 March, 2019](https://telegram.org/blog/unsend-privacy-emoji) in telegram clients). But you would have to use mtproto protocol and not the HTTP api I believe (as stated in the documentation I've attached in the answer)

Comment: ah ok thank you, so there isn't any app like this for javascript? I do not know PHP

Comment: These are in python but there are a couple of alternatives in JavaScript as well like [mtproto-core](https://github.com/alik0211/mtproto-core) and [GramJs](https://github.com/gram-js/gramjs)

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.command('delete', async (ctx) => {
    let i = 0;
    while(true) {
        try {
            await ctx.deleteMessage(ctx.message.message_id - i++);
        } catch(e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Also, a very similar code was already provided by [these answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66155706/3641635), thus i suggest you to remove your answer and instead add a comment on Kayra's answer regarding the asynchronous approach